# Conditional NaN Filling

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, null

I have a large dataframe with 11 columns where I want to replace NaN values with zeros, if every value in another group of columns is NaN, and otherwise to convert the number that is not null to an integer. I am doing this in the following way, but with only 8000 observations it is taking a long long time to complete (although it does so correctly). I reckon this took nearly 20 minutes:

```
lt = ['lost_time_a', 'lost_time_b', 'lost_time_c', 'lost_time_d', 'lost_time_e', 'lost_time_f', 'lost_time_g',
      'lost_time_h', 'lost_time_i', 'lost_time_j', 'ttl']
ht = ['hour1', 'hour2', 'hour3', 'hour4', 'hour5', 'hour6', 'hour7', 'hour8', 'hour9', 'hour10', 'hour11',
      'hour12', 'hour13', 'hour14', 'hour15']

for row in FinalDF.index:
    if not all([pd.isnull(FinalDF.loc[row, col]) for col in ht]):
        for Col_ in lt:
            val = FinalDF.loc[row, Col_]
            if pd.isnull(val):
                FinalDF.loc[row, Col_] = 0
            else:
                FinalDF.loc[row, Col_] = int(val)
```

All help appreciated

Here is some test data for you folks:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan as NA
FinalDF = pd.DataFrame({'hour1' : [NA, NA, NA, 70, 60],
                   'hour2' : [100, 50, NA, 120, 100],
                   'hour3' : [120, 80, NA, 130, 100],
                   'hour4' : [140, 90, NA, 120, 70],
                   'hour5' : [130, 200, NA, NA, NA],
                   'hour6' : [NA, NA, NA, 70, 60],
                   'hour7' : [100, 50, NA, 120, 100],
                   'hour8' : [120, 80, NA, 130, 100],
                   'hour9' : [140, 90, NA, 120, 70,],
                   'hour10' :[130, 200, NA, NA, NA],
                   'hour11' : [NA, NA, NA, 70, 60],
                   'hour12' : [100, 50, NA, 120, 100],
                   'hour13' : [120, 80, NA, 130, 100],
                   'hour14' : [140, 90, NA, 120, 70],
                   'hour15' : [130, 200, NA, NA, NA],
                   'lost_time_a' : [NA, NA, NA, NA, NA],
                   'lost_time_b' : [NA, 1.0, NA, NA, 4.1],
                   'lost_time_c' : [NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.1],
                   'lost_time_d' : [1, 2.3, NA, NA, 1],
                   'lost_time_e' : [NA, NA, NA, NA, NA],
                   'lost_time_f' : [NA, 1.0, NA, NA, 4.1],
                   'lost_time_g' : [NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.1],
                   'lost_time_h' : [1, 2.3, NA, NA, 1],
                   'lost_time_i' : [NA, NA, NA, NA, NA],
                   'lost_time_j' : [NA, 1.0, NA, NA, 4.1],
                   'ttl'         : [NA, NA, NA, NA, NA]})
```

Partial output (lost time variables)

```
Out[18]:
   lost_time_a  lost_time_b  lost_time_c  lost_time_d  lost_time_e
0            0            0            0            1            0
1            0            1            0            2            0
2          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
3            0            0            0            0            0
4            0            4           10            1            0
```

Comment: Could you make a self-contained example which people can copy-and-paste to test?

Comment: Have added test data relevant to the code snippet posted.

Answer (score 2):

I think this produces the same results as your code:

```
def fix(df, ht, lt):
    df = df.copy()
    to_fix = ~df[ht].isnull().all(axis=1), lt
    df.loc[to_fix] = df.loc[to_fix].fillna(0).astype(int)
    return df
```

(Obviously you can drop the copy if you're okay with an in-place change.)

```
>>> df.iloc[:,-5:]
   lost_time_g  lost_time_h  lost_time_i  lost_time_j  ttl
0          NaN          1.0          NaN          NaN  NaN
1          NaN          2.3          NaN          1.0  NaN
2          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  NaN
3          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  NaN
4         10.1          1.0          NaN          4.1  NaN
>>> fix(df, ht, lt).iloc[:, -5:]
   lost_time_g  lost_time_h  lost_time_i  lost_time_j  ttl
0            0            1            0            0    0
1            0            2            0            1    0
2          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  NaN
3            0            0            0            0    0
4           10            1            0            4    0
>>> from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
>>> assert_frame_equal(orig(df, ht, lt), fix(df, ht, lt))
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I think this would do what you want?  `cond` is a boolean series which is true when all the columns in `ht` are null.

```
for c in lt:
    cond = pd.isnull(FinalDF[ht]).all(axis=1)
    FinalDF[c] = np.where(cond, FinalDF[c].fillna(0).astype(int), FinalDF[c])
```